# method addMediaFromUrl() from spatie not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I want use spatie to get Google+ avatar, but when I try get it there is an error.

```php
$user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
$usertest=User::whereEmail($user->getemail())->first();

if(! $usertest){
$usertest=User::create([
    'name'=>$user->name,
    'email'=>$user->email,
    'password'=>bcrypt($user->id)
]);}

$usertest->addMediaFromUrl($user->avatar)->toMediaCollection('avatar');
auth()->loginUsingId($usertest->id);
return redirect('/');
```

error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Spatie\MediaLibrary\FileAdder\FileAdder::processMediaItem() must be an instance of Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMedia, instance of App\User given,

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have not added `HasMedia` interface and `HasMediaTrait` to `User` class:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable implements HasMedia {

    use HasMediaTrait;

    // ...

}
```